# c# converting list of BMP to array of DICOM files

Tags: c#, bmp, dicom

I can convert bitmap to DICOM using the following:

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FileName)));
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
                bmp.MakeTransparent(c);
                im.Import(bmp);
```

It works great.

Now I am trying to convert a list of bitmap images to a list of DICOM using:

```
    MySession.Current.dicomArray = new DicomImage[NFiles];
      MySession.Current.bmpArray = new Bitmap[NFiles];
.....
 for (int i = 0; i < NFiles; ++i)
                                {
                                    MySession.Current.bmpArray[i] =
                                        new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(
                                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                                                "~/" + ImagePath + files[i])));
                                }
    ......
          for (int i = 0; i < NFiles; ++i)
         {
           MySession.Current.dicomArray[i].Import(MySession.Current.bmpArray[i]);
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I can see all files in the bmpArray.  I guess I am using for statement wrong.  I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: This may seem straight forward, but make sure you declare all your variables. When I get that error, I can kick myself most of the time because I never typed `= new Variable()` when declaring something. Edit: Also, it may be saying it cant reference the physical file / folder. You should check if it exists before working with them.

Comment: The physical files exist; I can build bmpArray without errors.  The error is in  MySession.Current.dicomArray[i].Import(MySession.Current.bmpArray[i]);

Comment: Then the code is saying that you are trying to import something that doesn't exist. Although its hard to tell. Try adding some breakpoints to your code and step through it from there?

Comment: have you tried adding MySession.Current.dicomArray[i] = new DicomImage(); to the beginning of second loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @AdilMammadov in the comments above, the problem is due to the fact that you have not yet defined the individual members of the `dicomArray` array, so when you are calling the `Import` method in the second loop, you are invoking it on a `null` object.

If `DicomImage` has a public constructor (it is not clear from your question if it does), either add the line that Adil suggests:

```
MySession.Current.dicomArray[i] = new DicomImage();
```

before the `Import` line in the second loop.

Alternatively, use the LINQ method [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) to create the array:

```
MySession.Current.dicomArray = Enumerable.Repeat(new DicomImage(), NFiles).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you Anders, it worked great; except all images in the dicomArray are the last bmp image!